# How can I make `repo status` gather untracked filles under the top most untracked directory?

Tags: git, repo

I have a set of GIT repositories managed with the Google repo tool. Some of those repositories contain untracked directories ; not tracked yet, but still used.

When I run `git status` within one of those, it gives:

```
On branch develop
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    projects/demo_in2a/
    projects/demo_in2b/
    ...
```

But the `repo status` lists all the files like this:

```
project trunk/                                  branch develop
 --     projects/demo_in2a/Kbuild.mk
 --     projects/demo_in2a/Makefile
 --     projects/demo_in2a/static.c
 --     projects/demo_in2a/include/FreeRTOSConfig.h
 --     projects/demo_in2a/include/memory_pool.mdef
 --     projects/demo_in2a/include/service.h
 --     projects/demo_in2a/main.c
 --     projects/demo_in2a/defconfig
 --     projects/demo_in2a/run.py
 --     projects/demo_in2b/Kbuild.mk
 --     projects/demo_in2b/Makefile
 --     projects/demo_in2b/static.c
 --     projects/demo_in2b/include/FreeRTOSConfig.h
 --     projects/demo_in2b/include/memory_pool.mdef
 --     projects/demo_in2b/include/service.h
 --     projects/demo_in2b/main.c
 --     projects/demo_in2b/defconfig
 --     projects/demo_in2b/run.py
...
```

It looks like `repo` calls `git status` with the `-u` argument.. and it makes the overall status a bit messy and barely readable.

How can I make `repo status` gather untracked filles under the top most untracked directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use `repo forall`.

```
repo forall -p -c 'git status -s'
```

It runs `git status -s` in every repository. If a repository is not clean, it prints the path of the repository (with `-p`) and working tree status in the short-format.

```
project path/foo
?? a/
project path/bar
?? b/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know of the `-p` option .. I'll go with your workaround for now 